# Ranking missing edges in df1 w.r.t df2 based on score matrix

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my data:

```
data1 = {
    'node1': [1,1,1,2],
    'node2': [2,3,5,4],
    'weight': [1,1,1,1],
}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['node1', 'node2', 'weight'])

data2 = {
    'node1': [1,1,2,3],
    'node2': [4,5,4,5],
    'weight': [1,1,1,1],
}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['node1', 'node2', 'weight'])

score = np.array([
    [0.9, 0.7, 0.2, 0.6, 0.4],
    [0.7, 0.9, 0.6, 0.8, 0.3],
    [0.2, 0.6, 0.9, 0.4, 0.7],
    [0.6, 0.8, 0.4, 0.9, 0.3],
    [0.4, 0.3, 0.7, 0.3, 0.9],
])
```

I want to rank all the missing edges in `df1` in a vector according to the score matrix and then compare them with the dataframe `df2` in binary classification (1 or 0) to make a vector of the form `[1, 1, 1, 0, ...]`.

The process is as follows:

```
# missing edges
1-4, 2-3, 2-5, 3-4, 4-5, 3-5
# scores of these edges
0.6, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.7

# missing edges sorted by their scores
3-5, 1-4, 2-3, 2-5, 3-4, 4-5
```

Now, comparing this list with the edges found in `df2`, we get:

```
# edges in 'df2'
3-5, 1-4
```

Final output is:

```
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: You have the missing edges as a list or df right ?

Comment: we have to calculate the missing edges based on df1

Comment: How even though we find that there will  less than or equal to four pairs will be missing based on given data but you have provided six.

Comment: the edges in df1 will be 1-2,1-3,1-5,2-4 and since this is undirected therefore 1 will have the missing edges 1-4,2 will have missing edges 2-3 2-5 and so on..the missing edges mean the total no of edges possible of the node -the nodes existing(w/0 considering self loops)

Comment: @Bharath since it is undirected we only take for eg 1,2 and not 2,1

Comment: is it anywhere related to networkx ? I dont think its just a plain pandas question

Comment: @Bharath but I am not using networkx graph object as a data input